# Datatables select only filtered content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In [this](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html) example

Try search for "`airi`" - only one result will show.

Try Submit the form, you can easily see the next row (actually the enrire table) gets submitted also.

How can I do so it is only the filtered rows that gets submitted?

Best regards

Comment: On submit of form, try to remove all hidden rows of table or submit data of visible rows only.

Comment: Yes that is what i would like to do. Submit only the visible rows. But how?

Comment: Please share code for submitting form and how you are calling datatable plugin. It is better if you can share a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('button').click( function() {
        var data = table.$('input:visible, select:visible').serialize();
        alert(
            "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+
            data.substr( 0, 120 )+'...'
        );
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much. I did search the net but nothing helped me. Did you just know that? Or where did you get that info? Best regards

Comment: I often use this selector, so the answer was obviously! ;) jQuery owns many [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) dedicated to different usages, they are very useful! Regards